# Django: Using south on project with existing migration files

Tags: django, web, django-south

This is a very basic question, but the other SO questions I read do not seam to answer it.

I checked out a project from a repository which contains some models some of them having migrations files. 
I did not create any local database yet

What is the correct way of creating all the tables for the project?

I thought I start by executing

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

this creates some tables but for the once using south it tells me to run migrate. So I execute

```
./manage.py migrate
```

but then I get the error that

```
DatabaseError: table "mytable" already exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `./manage.py syncdb --migrate` and it does not throw that kind of error.

Are you sure that none of you other apps use a table with the same name?

You can checkout which tables your app wants to create by opening a django shell and doing sth like:

./manage.py sql YourAppName

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact I got it to work now by only executing the manage.py syncdb --all command, does this make sense?